# setting up development environment for PHONEGAP

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

Starting with phonegap and installed the following:

ANT from apache

ANDROID SDK (which includes SDK + ECLIPSE + ADT PLUGIN)

now as guided here [phonegap documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android) i am trying to check proper functioning of following commands

1. java
2. ant

java commands run fine. But when do the ant, i get the following:

```
C:\Users\Mrinal>ant
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
```

Is it a normal behavior? Also I do not understand the fourth step in the above link.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal. It means Ant is properly running on your machine.

Now follow the [Getting Started guide for Android](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android)

Comment: yes i am on fourth step but it fails when i issue a create command. I get this: 

C:\android\phonegap\lib\android\bin>create
Cannot locate javac.exe using the PATH environment variable.
Retry after adding directory containing javac.exe to the PATH variable.
Remember to open a new command window after updating the PATH variable.
Visit http://java.oracle.com if you need to install Java (JDK).

Comment: you need to set java path variable in environment variable. follow this guide http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Comment: now i get this: c:\android\phonegap\lib\android\bin>create
Cannot locate android.bat using the PATH environment variable.
Retry after adding directory containing android.bat to the PATH variable.
Remember to open a new command window after updating the PATH variable.
Visit http://developer.android.com if you need to install the Android SDK.

Comment: did you set path for Android sdk?

Comment: C:\Users\Mrinal\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\android\development;c:\ant\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin. IN android\development i have sdk installed with two directories: eclipse, sdk and a file called sdk manager.

Comment: you have not set path to your Android sdk. check 3B. section of the link I've given in the answer. You need to set path to `C:\Development\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools;C:\Development\android-sdk-windows\tools`

Comment: I just added this. ;C:\android\development\sdk\platform-tools; Dont see that tools directory in the same context.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30742/discussion-between-benerd-and-mayu-mayooresan)